# How to start with chainbase?

Tags: chainbase

I am reading chainbase, and I wonder if anyone have idea to start with chainbase? This means: what does it flows, and if I write directly to disk, it is fine?
 Because I see in chainbase class, I see it has some functions as squash, undo,.. I do not know the actually of flow data in EOS and those function used to fork db and does not involved to chainbase right?

Comment: Good resources for those with similar questions, but does not answer current question: https://github.com/EOSIO/chainbase | https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2047/what-is-the-chainbase-database-used-for

Comment: Thank you very much, I read it, but I still not clear with it. Maybe I am lack of technical for this

Comment: We all lack technical for this :).  I just wanted to include those links in the hopes that someone else may be able to use them to help answer your question.